# Web Development PHP for Moodle: Echo not working

Tags: php, web, moodle

I am developing a plugin for Moodle and I am struggling with some basic PHP set up.

My database and docker etc. is set up and I have written some functioning code that is storing stuff in my database.

At the moment I am trying to do something basic but I am getting an error so I think I am missing some PHP set up.

I have tried this at first with some objects print_r() dump_value() and echo. All are throwing  errors in chrome so I decided to try just printing a string as follows.

```
$sql = <<<END
        SELECT COURSE.id, COURSE.fullname, COURSE.shortname, CAT.name AS category
        FROM {course} COURSE LEFT JOIN {course_categories} CAT ON COURSE.category = CAT.id
        WHERE COURSE.id = ?
        END;

$record = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array($courseid))[$courseid];

echo "No";
```

is throwing an error in chrome

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'N', "No[{"error"... is not valid JSON
```

Would appreciate any help and pointers.

I expected this to just print No in the console in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are outputting something within a webservice. Webservices expect a JSON-formatted response (which is generated by the webservice wrapper - the webservice function itself just returns an object, which is then formatted as JSON). If the Moodle Javascript, sending the AJAX request to the webservice, sees anything other than valid JSON in the response, then it produces the error you have mentioned.

If you want to debug your code, do not insert "echo" statements, instead install [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) on your local server, then use a suitable IDE (I use PHPStorm, but I'm told that Netbeans, VSCode and many others have similar functionality) to set breakpoints in your code and step through to see what is happening.